# Small world map?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using leaflet.js to render tiles from openstreetmap.  I have it working fine.  I would like to display the entire world map (zoom level 0). This also works fine.  My problem is that on zoom level 0 the world is kind of big.  Is it possible to render the world map in a div 100px wide, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change the width or height of the div containing the map, use CSS,
like this:

```
<style>
#map{
width:100px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, maRtin.  Yes, this does work, however I still cannot see the entire world in a map less than 256x256.  From what I can tell this is the dimension of zoom level 0?  Do you know if it is possible to see the entire world in 100x100 for example?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: One tile has a size of 256x256 px, you are right. On zoom level 0 you only see one tile, however the world is stretched to fit this tile perfectly. If you want to use a tiledlayer, a map smaller than 256x256 will never will be able to display the whole extent of the world. Atleast what I know. 
If you found my answer above helpful, please give me an upvote. thx

Comment: I don't like your answer but I will accept it as the truth, thank you for your help :-)

Comment: A solution to your problem might be to save the tile (i.e. via a screenshot) resize it to 100x100px in photoshop and then use this single tile as a background to your leaflet map. This is a big workaround and you wont be able to zoom in into deeper tile levels anymore